# Select Except the duplicate Records from the table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that has duplicate entries in one of the columns  e.g.:

```
  +----+-----------+------------+
  | id | object_id | status_val |
  +----+-----------+------------+
  |  1 |         1 |          0 | 
  |  2 |         1 |          0 | 
  |  3 |         1 |          0 | 
  |  4 |         2 |          0 | 
  |  5 |         3 |          0 | 
  |  6 |         4 |          0 | 
  |  7 |         4 |          0 | 
  +----+-----------+------------+
```

I need the output to be like this:

```
  +----+-----------+------------+
  | id | object_id | status_val |
  +----+-----------+------------+
  |  4 |         2 |          0 | 
  |  5 |         3 |          0 | 
  +----+-----------+------------+
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: i think Matt & yossi answer are  good so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM <yourTable> t1
WHERE t1.object_id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT t2.object_id
    FROM <yourTable> t2 
    GROUP BY t2.object_id
    HAVING COUNT(object_id) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select min(id), 
       object_id, 
       min(status_val) 
from table 
group by object_id 
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT object_id
FROM object_table ) as row_count, status_val,id,object_id FROM object_table where row_count = 1;
```

I think you are looking for that

Comment: Remove quote from ``object_table`` please.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT MIN(id) id, object_id, MIN(status_val) status_val
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING COUNT(object_id) = 1
```

Output

```
id  object_id status_val
4   2         0
5   3         0
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f643f/9/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` for unique record like below :-

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME
    group by TABLE_COLOUM_NAME
```

This query give you only unique value from your Table.

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number for each row partitioned and ordered by the columns `[object_id]`, `[status_val]`. Then from the result set select the rows which having maximum row number 1.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [object_id], [status_val]
        order by [object_id], [status_val]
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select min([id]) as [id], [object_id], [status_val]
from cte
group by [object_id], [status_val]
having max([rn]) = 1;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f427/1)**